# Cross-validating `glmnet` using `caret`

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, r-caret, glmnet

I am going through [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) book and I'm trying to find the best lambda for a Ridge regression model using 10-fold cross-validation. I have tried both `cv.glmnet` and `caret` `train` functions with very similar configurations, but I'm getting very different results:

### Initial Setup

```
library(ISLR)
library(glmnet)
library(caret)
hit = na.omit(Hitters)

grid = 10 ^ seq(10, -2, length= 100) # from 10B to .01, the grid for lambda
x = model.matrix(Salary ~ ., hit)[,-1]
y = hit$Salary

train.x = x[inTrain,]
train.y = y[inTrain]
test.x = x[-inTrain,]
test.y = y[-inTrain]
```

### Using `cv.glmnet`

```
set.seed(1)
cv.out = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, nfolds = 10,
               type.measure = "mse", lambda = grid)

best.lam = cv.out$lambda.min
best.lam
#231.013

cv.out$cvm[which(cv.out$lambda == cv.out$lambda.min)]
# mean cross-validated MSE: 120385.5
```

### Using `caret`

```
ridge.model.caret = train(x, y, method = "glmnet",
                      tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = grid),
                      tuneLength = 100, metric = "RMSE",
                      trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10))
ridge.model.caret$bestTune
# 18.73

ridge.model.caret$results$RMSE[which.min(ridge.model.caret$results$RMSE)]^2
# mean cross-validated MSE: 108339
```

Would you please help me figure out what I'm missing? Does it mean that these 2 different lambdas have close enough results?

Comment: You don't define `inTrain` anywhere. Also, set the seed prior to calling `train` so that we can reproduce the issue and give the results of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Also, do you mean to fit the models to `x` and `y`? You did split the data into training and test.